# How to enable inbound port in Hyper-V inside Azure VM?

Tags: virtualization, azure-virtual-machine, hyper-v, azure-virtual-network

**Problem Description**

We used to set up an Ubuntu Azure VM (consider Private IP as 109.11.23.11) for sending some simulated data. We need to set up multiple azure VM's for each one for every simulator.

For that simulator to send data outside we specify an inbound rule for the specific port as below

[image: Inbound Rule]

Here for data receiver we specify the connection details as below
:
Ex: ***109.11.23.11:50000***

Instead of doing that I want to try out having one Azure Windows Server VM which contains multiple Ubuntu Hyper-V machines

Then I set up that Windows server machine and then enabled Hyper-V. And then setup a virtual network to be used by Hyper V using the below Powershell script

```
New-VMSwitch -Name VmNAT -SwitchType Internal
New-NetNat -Name LocalNAT -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix "192.168.49.0/24"
Get-NetAdapter "vEthernet (VmNat)" | New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.49.1 -AddressFamily IPv4 -PrefixLength 24
Install-WindowsFeature -Name 'DHCP' –IncludeManagementTools
Add-DhcpServerV4Scope -Name "DHCP Scope" -StartRange 192.168.49.50 -EndRange 192.168.49.250 -SubnetMask 255.255.255.0
Set-DhcpServerV4OptionValue -DnsServer 168.63.129.16 -Router 192.168.49.1
```

Now I am a bit confused about how to open up port 50000 as in the earlier method for this Hyper-V.

**What I tried**

I created an inbound rule in the host VM as we have done in the Ubuntu VM earlier. And in the receiver tried giving the public IP of the host machine/Ubuntu Hyper V separately. Both of these things failed. The receiver is not getting connected to this simulator VM as earlier. I did not try with the host machine's private IP yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT Let me try this out and let you know. I am working on other things and am unable to update you on this.

Comment: Hey @KBNanda had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT Sorry I was busy with other work and did not try this out yet. I will definitely get back when the scenario arises to try this out.

Answer (score 1):

•   Since, you have created a **‘NAT’** subnet and attached an additional NIC (Network Interface Card) to the Azure VM in this subnet which communicates and manages the IP addresses for the nested VMs on the Azure VM, and a regular LAN (Local Area Network) subnet on which the host Azure VM is placed, please ensure that an inbound rule exists for Port 50000 in the NSG (Network Security Group) for the ‘NAT’ subnet NIC. Also, ensure that the network architecture of the nested VMs hosted on Azure VM is as below: -

[image: Azure nested VMs]

•   Then, also ensure that a **virtual switch** is created on the Azure VM to forward traffic from the nested VMs via host Azure VM to the internet and vice versa. Execute the below powershell command to add **NAT static mapping** with the external IP address used by the Azure VM: -

```
   Add-NetNatStaticMapping -NatName "NestedSwitch" -Protocol TCP -ExternalIPAddress 0.0.0.0 -InternalIPAddress 10.4.2.2 -InternalPort 5000 -ExternalPort 5000
```

Also, create an **inbound firewall rule** on the Azure host VM by executing the below powershell command for internal switch created on Hyper-V: -

New-NetFirewallRule -RemoteAddress 192.168.217.0/24 -DisplayName "Allow217net" -Profile Any -Action Allow

Also, ensure that port forwarding is enabled for inbound access to happen from the RDP port to the nested VMs on the nested VMs subnet. So, execute the below command on the host Azure VM to forward the traffic to the concerned ports: -

```
Add-NetNatStaticMapping -ExternalIPAddress "0.0.0.0/24" -ExternalPort 50004 -Protocol TCP -InternalIPAddress "192.168.0.4" -InternalPort 3389 -NatName NATNetwork
```

Also, ensure that the below command is executed on the Azure VM to map the listening port to the required NIC on the nested VMs: -

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=<nat address> listenport=<random port> connectaddress=<nested vm address> connectport=<nested vm service port>
```

The above solutions should help you to resolve your issue for inbound rules on the nested VMs.